# Error Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

estoy intentando ingresas informacion a mi base de datos pero a la hora de hacerlo me genera esta error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <?php

include('con_db.php');
print_r($_POST);

$codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
$documento_id = $_POST["documento_id"];
$primer_nombre = $_POST["primer_nombre"];
$segundo_nombre = $_POST["segundo_nombre"];
$primer_apellido = $_POST["primer_apellido"];
$segundo_apellido = $_POST["segundo_apellido"];
$programa = $_POST["programa"];
$fecha_naci = $_POST["fecha_naci"];
$celular = $_POST["celular"];
$sexo = $_POST["sexo"];
$sql = "INSERT into estudiantes(codigo, documento-id, primer-nomb, segundo-nomb, primer-apell, segundo-apell, programa, fecha-naci, celular, sexo) VALUES ('$codigo','$documento_id','$primer_nombre','$segundo_nombre','$primer_apellido','$segundo_apellido','$programa','$fecha_naci','$celular','$sexo')";
$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
if ($ejecutar) {
    echo 'Ta BIEN';
}
else{
    echo 'Ta MAL';
}


?>
```

Porfavor ayuda, es para un trabajo y no encuentro solucion, porfavor :(

Comment: si las tablas tienen guiones en su nombre, tienes que encerrar los identificadores entre comillas invertidas ` o "back ticks". Mysql está confundido porque no entiende el guión. Si fuese un guion bajo, es diferente, pero veo no es el caso.

Comment: Si te fijas, cuando traes los datos del post, tienes guiones bajos. cuando haces el insert, tienes guiones normales.

Comment: @Arriel muchas gracias la verdad nos dimos cuenta despues, muchisimas gracias 7w7, lo cambiamos todo